# How do I rsync directories if remote directory's name matches?

Tags: bash, cron, directory, rsync

I am trying to set up a `cron` job on macOS that will sync the `assets` directory if `local/master/{client-name}/`  matches the same `{client-name}` as the directory in `remote/shared/clients/{client-name}`.

I will only be adding files to `local`, and pushing that sync to `remote`.

I know I can do something like `rsync local/master/clientA/assets remote/clients/assets` but I need it to automate, even if that means separate commands for each folder.

[image: Local and Remote File Structures]

Comment: Not a programming question... Better use `tree` command line and paste question + tree text on superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: i'd imagine you can inspect folder structure using sftp